# ORA-03135 connection lost contact while trying to connect to DB using python and cx_Oracle module

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle12c, cx-oracle

I'm trying to connect to the oracle db using **cx_Oracle** and **python** on **Windows 10** system (based on https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/installation.html#installing-cx-oracle-on-windows) like below:

```
import cx_Oracle

dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('host', 'port', service_name='name')
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user='username', password='passwd', dsn=dsn_tns)
```

And i've got an error:

> cx_Oracle.OperationalError: ORA-03135: connection lost contact
>
> Process ID: 0
> Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0

I've also add 2 parameters to **sqlnet.ora** (based on info from: https://www.vitalsofttech.com/ora-03135-connection-lost-contact/):

- SQLNET.EXPIRE_TIME=10
- SQLNET.INBOUND_CONNECT_TIMEOUT=3

Still raising the same error.

I was thinking that maybe it can be a problem with firewall, but it's not. Also I can connect to database from command line using **sqlplus**.

**Tnsping** to the database from my local machine returns OK.

Comment: You'll need to provide more information -- like how long it takes before the error is produced? Does it happen every time with exactly the same time period? The error suggests a network failure. Can you rule that out?

Comment: If this error occurs right at connection, make sure your DB user has been granted the CREATE SESSION privilege.

Comment: @ChristopherJones Thanks for answer. I have CREATE SESSION privilege.

Comment: @AnthonyTuininga For sure it's not a problem with a network failure. It happens every single time when I'm trying to connect to DB via my python script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved.

Upgrading **Oracle instant client** on my local machine from **11.2** to **12.1** solved the problem of connectivity.